# Why is my forms content showing in the title for my edit function? Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, cs50

I am currently doing an assignment where one of the requirements for the edit function is that the user should be able to click on an edit button and be taken to a page where they have the option of editing what they wrote before.

The issue I am having is that I am using INITIAL to push the previously populated content so that it will show, but this keeps showing on the title of the page instead of inside the textarea content.

I have tried to tweak this but after several attempts, I keep getting the same issue, when i submit this, it gives me a new entry/page when what I want to do is edit the page and not create a new page.

VIEWS.PY

```
class AddPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
        })
    )
    
def edit_page(request, title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        title = title
        content = util.get_entry(title)
        form = AddPageForm({"title": title, "content": content})
        return render(
            request,
            "encyclopedia/editpage.html",
            {"form": form, "title": title}
        )

    form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data.get("title")
        content = form.cleaned_data.get("content")

        util.save_entry(title=title, content=content)
        return redirect('encyclopedia:entrypage', title)
```

EDIT PAGE

```
{% block body %}

    <h1>Edit</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:editpage' title %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

ENTRY PAGE

```
{% block body %}
        {{ content|safe }}

        <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:editpage' title %}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>


{% endblock %}
```

URLS.PY

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry_page, name="entrypage"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_page", views.add_page, name="addpage"),
    path("edit_page/<str:title>", views.edit_page, name="editpage")

]
```

Answer (score 0):

in get_entry function you're getting object right? if yes
change your view to something like this

```
    content = util.get_entry(title)
    form = AddPageForm({"title": title, "content": content.content})
```

Comment: this gives me this error                                                                                         
```AttributeError at /edit_page/Testing to see if the bug I have had has been corrected
'str' object has no attribute 'content'```

Comment: can you show me your get_entry function?